# Proving something about $|f(x)|$ when the lim of $f(x)/x^2$ is known

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value, continued-fractions

I've been trying to crack this issue for 2 days and I got pretty much nothing

Given that $f$ is a continuous function 
and the following limits exists and are **finite**:
$$
(1) \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}             (2) \lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}
$$

I need to prove that there are constants $a$ and $b$ such that for every $x\in\Bbb R$ the following is true
$$
|f(x)|\le ax^2+b
$$

I was thinking to split the proof to 3 parts $(\infty, M_1)$, $[M_1,M_2]$, $[M_2,\infty)$

Thank you very much

Comment: Your basic strategy is sound. How are you going to choose $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Comment: Probably by using the basic definition of finite limit when $x\to\pm\infty$ , choosing some $\epsilon$ for both and getting $M_1$ and $M_2$

Comment: Exactly! Alex Becker's answer uses $\epsilon = 1$, but any positive $\epsilon$ will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can indeed divide it up in that manner. Let $L_1$ be the limit at $-\infty$ and $L_2$ the limit at $+\infty$. By definition, we have some $M_1,M_2$ such that
$$x<M_1\implies \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^2}-L_1\right|<1\quad \text{and}\quad x>M_2 \implies \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^2}-L_2\right|<1$$
and thus
$$x<M_1\implies |f(x)|<(|L_1|+1)x^2\quad \text{and}\quad x>M_2 \implies |f(x)|<(|L_2|+1)x^2$$
so if we let $a=\max(|L_1|+1,|L_2|+1)$ and $b=\sup_{x\in [M_1,M_2]}|f(x)|$ which exists by continuity, $|f(x)|\leq ax^2+b$.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. But, don't you assume here that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are positive?

Comment: @user144063 Good catch. I'll fix that.

Comment: Thankyou, 
Another minor fix - $b$ should be set to $max$ and not $sup$ (according to [Extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) such $max$ exists) and therefor $|f(x)|{\le}ax^2+b$ and not just $<$ (if the max is in the point where $x=0$ then $|f(x)|=b$. again - thankyou very much!

Comment: @user144063 $\max$ and $\sup$ agree whenever the former exists. Here it doesn't matter since $\max$ always exists for a cts function on a closed interval.

Comment: That's right, the only little difference here is that the question was with less than **or equal** - which by solely saying $sup$ we don't get

Comment: @user144063 No, there's literally no difference. For any set $s$ and function $f:S\to X$, if $\max_{x\in S}f(x)$ exists then $\max_{x\in S}f(x)=\sup_{x\in S}f(x)$.